# valueMap returning empty object with Neptune

Tags: node.js, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, gremlinjs

First let me say two things: I'm starting with graphDB and I tried this post: [Gremlin's valueMap() returns an empty object with JS and Neptune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552964/gremlins-valuemap-returns-an-empty-object-with-js-and-neptune) and did not work.

I'm following the same steps as I'm using in the `gremlin` console. In the console is working 100%.
In `gremlin` console:

```bash
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userUuid', '12345').out('knows').order().by(out('knows').count(), desc).range(0, 20).hasLabel('user').valueMap('userUuid', 'username', 'email')
```

This query is returning:
[image]

Now, the following `NodeJs` code is not working with the `valueMap` function.

```js
  const value = await g.V().hasLabel(constants.USER)
            .has(constants.USER_UUID, '12345')
            .out('knows')
            .order()
            .by(__.out('knows').count(), gremlin.process.order.desc)
            .range(pageIndex, pageSize)
            .valueMap(constants.USER_UUID, constants.USERNAME, constants.EMAIL)
            .toList();
```

The above code is returning:

```
Response: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Note: if I remove the `.valueMap(constants.USER_UUID, constants.USERNAME, constants.EMAIL)`, the function will return the values as list, instead of mapped into objects for each position inside the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this post on AWS:
[image]

And there is a link to this post here on SOF:
[Issue with .project().by() in Gremlin JS 3.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226192/issue-with-project-by-in-gremlin-js-3-4-0)

This works for me.